# C# Dependency Injection and dll loading exception

Tags: c#, dll, dependency-injection

I am creating a project which should be used on Windows and Linux machines. The solution contains 3 projects: Win - Windows native functions implementation, Lin - Linux native functions implementation and Core - project which contains all dependencies and resolves them based on runtime information.
Win project has a target framework: .Net framework 4.6.2, Linux project: - .Net standard 2.0 and Core project is multitarget:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

The problem here is that some class in Win project uses `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes` Windows specific DLLs. And while I am running my project in VS, if the application calls that class, I receive following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'UIAutomationClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

in Win project.

I tried to change Core.csproj file and add these lines:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net462'">
  <Reference Include="UIAutomationClient"/>
  <Reference Include="UIAutomationTypes"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it adds references, while the exception still exist. 
Help me please to figure out how to solve this problem. 
I will provide more code if it's needed.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try actually searching for the DLL's on your pc? They might be missing

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't `.net Framework 4.6.2` implement `.net Standard 2.0`? Why do you target both?

Comment: @AviMeltser, yes. they exist in ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2```

Comment: @vasily.sib. I suppose that I might be wrong here, but the idea is that Core project targets both platforms because Lin project targets ```.net Standard 2.0``` and Win project targets ```. net Framework 4.6.2```. Also, Core project is used  in ```.net core 2.1``` project

Comment: you may found [this post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx) usefull

Comment: @vasily.sib, thank you. there was another problem